# JQUERY IE 7,8 Error Message: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

```
Line: 151
Character: 6
Code: 0
Error Message: Expected identifier, string or number
```

The script works fine in chrome, ff, opera but comes up with the above error in ei 6,7 and 8 and doesnt even fire the click event.

**EDIT one person pointed out there was a comma that didnt need to be there so I removed it and got this error**

```
Line: 232
Character: 3
Code: 0
Error Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**Here is the original code  EDITED REMOVED Commas as said above**

```
   <?php
switch($_GET['size']){
case"3metre":
$panelwidth=75;
$panelheight=69;
break;
case"4metre":
$panelwidth=89;
$panelheight=69;
break;
};

$fourpanels = $panelwidth * 4;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- JS -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/validator/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>



<!-- STYLES -->

<style>
<!-- LAYOUT -->


<!-- SKIRTS -->
.panelContainer{
height:128px;
width:900px;
float:left; 
}

.endpanel{
width:<?php echo $panelwidth*2;?>px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}
.panel{
width:<?php echo $panelwidth*2;?>px;
bottom:0;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}

.mid{
    border-left:0px;
    }

.door:hover{
width:<?php echo $panelwidth*2;?>px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}

.panelselected{
width:<?php echo $panelwidth*2;?>px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}
.container{
    min-width:<?php echo $panelwidth*2;?>px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    height:7px; 
    }

.button{
    width:7px; height:7px;
    margin:3px;

    }
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}





</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:780px; height:80px;float:left;">
    <h3>Please select a panel and customise the width and height to fit under your door step / doorway</h3>       

     <ul>
        <li>Total Draught Skirt Width: <input type="text" disabled id="totalwidth" value="<?php echo $panelwidth*5;?>"/>(CMS)   </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<!-- CUSTOMISE DOOR -->


<div style="margin-top:20px; min-width:780px; height:80px;float:left;position:relative;">
        <div class="endpanel" id="panel1">
            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left"/>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel mid door">

        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div id="panel4" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div class="endpanel mid" id="panel5">
            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right"/>
        </div>
</div>

   <div id="customisedoor" style="clear:both; margin-top:50px;width:400px; height:80px;float:left; display:none;">


        <strong>Customise Your Door Panel</strong>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="width" id="doorwidth" value="<?php echo $panelwidth;?>"/>(CMS)
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Height From Top of Skirt: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="height" id="doorheight" value="30"/>(CMS)
            </td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">



///////////
     $("div.door").click(function () {

          $("div.door").removeClass("panelselected");
          $(this).toggleClass("panelselected");
          selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
          resetall();
          alert("IDis"+selectedID);
          $("#customisedoor").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px"

           }, 200 );
           height = 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
           topmargin = Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
          $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px");
          ////////////////////////////IF PANEL 2
          if(selectedID === 'panel2'){
$("#panel1").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>');
          }
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel3'){
$("#panel2").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel4").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel4'){
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel5").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
    });

    $("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: Number($("#doorwidth").val())*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    $("#doorwidth").click(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    function calculateheight(){
         $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2+"px"

              }, 200 );
              height = 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2;
              topmargin = $("#doorheight").val()*2;
        $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px")
    }

        $("#doorheight").keyup(function (){
          calculateheight();
          });

        $("#doorheight").click(function (){
          calculateheight();

    });

    function resetall(){
        $(".appended").remove();
        $(".door").css({'width':'150','height':'118','margin':'0px'});
        $(".door").removeClass("panelselected");
        $("#doorheight").val(30);
        $("#doorwidth").val(75);
        $("#totalwidth").val(300+$("#doorwidth").val());

    }

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        //alert("removed");
        resetall();
    });
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(function() {
        //$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
        //$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });

        $( "#b2" ).draggable({ containment: "#bc2", scroll: false });
        //$( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ containment: "#demo-frame" });
        //$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Source From IE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- JS -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/validator/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>



<!-- STYLES -->

<style>
<!-- LAYOUT -->


<!-- SKIRTS -->
.panelContainer{
height:128px;
width:900px;
float:left; 
}

.endpanel{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}
.panel{
width:150px;
bottom:0;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}

.mid{
    border-left:0px;
    }

.door:hover{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}

.panelselected{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}
.container{
    min-width:150px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    height:7px; 
    }

.button{
    width:7px; height:7px;
    margin:3px;

    }
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}





</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:780px; height:80px;float:left;">
    <h3>Please select a panel and customise the width and height to fit under your door step / doorway</h3>       

     <ul>
        <li>Total Draught Skirt Width: <input type="text" disabled id="totalwidth" value="375"/>(CMS)   </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<!-- CUSTOMISE DOOR -->


<div style="margin-top:20px; min-width:780px; height:80px;float:left;position:relative;">
        <div class="endpanel" id="panel1">
            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left"/>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel mid door">

        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div id="panel4" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div class="endpanel mid" id="panel5">
            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right"/>
        </div>
</div>

   <div id="customisedoor" style="clear:both; margin-top:50px;width:400px; height:80px;float:left; display:none;">


        <strong>Customise Your Door Panel</strong>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="width" id="doorwidth" value="75"/>(CMS)
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Height From Top of Skirt: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="height" id="doorheight" value="30"/>(CMS)
            </td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">



///////////
     $("div.door").click(function () {

          $("div.door").removeClass("panelselected");
          $(this).toggleClass("panelselected");
          selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
          resetall();
          alert("IDis"+selectedID);
          $("#customisedoor").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px"

           }, 200 );
           height = 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
           topmargin = Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
          $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px");
          ////////////////////////////IF PANEL 2
          if(selectedID === 'panel2'){
$("#panel1").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>');
          }
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel3'){
$("#panel2").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel4").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel4'){
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel5").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
    });

    $("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: Number($("#doorwidth").val())*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    $("#doorwidth").click(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    function calculateheight(){
         $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2+"px"

              }, 200 );
              height = 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2;
              topmargin = $("#doorheight").val()*2;
        $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px")
    }

        $("#doorheight").keyup(function (){
          calculateheight();
          });

        $("#doorheight").click(function (){
          calculateheight();

    });

    function resetall(){
        $(".appended").remove();
        $(".door").css({'width':'150','height':'118','margin':'0px'});
        $(".door").removeClass("panelselected");
        $("#doorheight").val(30);
        $("#doorwidth").val(75);
        $("#totalwidth").val(300+$("#doorwidth").val());

    }

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        //alert("removed");
        resetall();
    });
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(function() {
        //$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
        //$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });

        $( "#b2" ).draggable({ containment: "#bc2", scroll: false });
        //$( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ containment: "#demo-frame" });
        //$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the source output from your browser so we can cross check the line numbers?

Comment: Shouldn't you be prefixing your variables with `var`? e.g. `var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really wrap your javascript code in a jQuery document ready event. While bindings may be applied outside the ready event, putting them inside will guarantee that the document is ready to have custom events bound. This is especially important for browser with slow javascript implementations, such as Internet Explorer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // put all your javascript code here
});
```

Comment: see edited post, i wrapped the code in jquery doc ready and it now works however i still get this error 

Line: 152
Character: 6
Code: 0
Error Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I would comment out or remove all javascript code and see if the error message goes away. Then add in the code chunk at a time, until you get the error message, now we know which chunk of code is the culprit. If you could post that here I might be able to help more, I don't have my Windows VM handy right now...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, line 151 is somewhere arround this :

```
$("#"+selectedID).animate({
    height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px",

}, 200 );
```

Note there is a comma at the end of the second line.

**This comma is after the last element of an object** -- and you cannot have a comma after the last item of an object<sup>1</sup> : remove it.

Of course, you will have to do the same modifications in some other places where you made the same mistake -- like in the `calculateheight()` function.

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>Even if some browser, like Firefox, don't raise an error.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The comma after "px" should not be there, it causes IE to throw that error:

```
$("#"+selectedID).animate({
    height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px",
}, 200 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the compatibility View issue in case of IE.
step1: Goto->Tool->Compatibility View Settings
Clear all check boxes

step2: Goto->Tool->Compatibility View
undo the selection